# Convert unicode (UTF-8) filenames to ANSI (DOS)

Tags: windows, utf-8, filenames

Directory listing with broken filenames encoding

```
C:\Downloads\1>dir
18.01.2010  10:45    <DIR>          РЎР?Р>Р?Р?С?Р+
18.01.2010  10:45    <DIR>          Р?Р?С'Р?Р>Р?Рє
18.01.2010  10:45    <DIR>          Р"Р?С?Р?Р°С╪Р°-Р>РчС╪РчР+Р?Рё РєР?С?РїС?С?
18.01.2010  10:45    <DIR>          Р•Р>Р•Р?РўР Р?Р?Р?
```

Is there any tools for windows to convert filenames from UTF-8 to ANSI?

Comment: I believe this question was asked on the wrong forum. Either you need a power user tool (serverfault, codeproject, whatever...), and giving a link as an answer could be acceptable, or you need the source code (or at least source code fragments) to do it, and then the question is wrongly asked, and your answer below is inappropriate.

Comment: I confirm: This question should have been asked on superuser: This one http://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux is similar (how to convert something on Linux)

Comment: @paercebal that's a terrible example, for conversion of a complex filetype. People landing here are looking for a perl one liner or Python decode().encode(), or maybe (at that time) the Ruby iconv.  This is just for the file names, not the content. If he had tried in bash it would have belonged here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one. I made it by myself today.

```
unit main;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,      Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, ExtCtrls, SHLOBJ, Buttons, Grids;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button3: TButton;
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Panel4: TPanel;
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{$LongStrings On}
procedure FindFiles(FilesList: TStringList; StartDir, FileMask: string);
var

  SR: TSearchRec;
  DirList: TStringList;
  IsFound: Boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  if StartDir[length(StartDir)] <> '\' then
    StartDir := StartDir + '\';
  IsFound :=    FindFirst('\\?\' + StartDir+FileMask, faAnyFile-faDirectory, SR) = 0;
  while IsFound do begin
    FilesList.Add(StartDir + SR.Name);
    IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
  end;
  FindClose(SR);

  DirList := TStringList.Create;
  IsFound := FindFirst('\\?\' + StartDir + '*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0;
  while IsFound do begin
    if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) and
         (SR.Name[1] <> '.') then
      DirList.Add(StartDir + SR.Name);
    IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
  end;
  FindClose(SR);

  for i := 0 to DirList.Count - 1 do
    FindFiles(FilesList, DirList[i], FileMask);
  DirList.Free;
end;

function BrowseForFolder(var Foldr: string; Title: string): Boolean;
var
  BrowseInfo: TBrowseInfo;
  ItemIDList: PItemIDList;
  DisplayName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  Result := False;
  FillChar(BrowseInfo, SizeOf(BrowseInfo), #0);
  with BrowseInfo do begin
    hwndOwner := Application.Handle;
    pszDisplayName := @DisplayName[0];
    lpszTitle := PChar(Title);
    ulFlags := BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;
  end;
  ItemIDList := SHBrowseForFolder(BrowseInfo);
  if Assigned(ItemIDList) then
    if SHGetPathFromIDList(ItemIDList, DisplayName) then begin
      Foldr := DisplayName;
      Result := True;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Foldr: string;
  FilesList: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin

  if BrowseForFolder(Foldr, 'Select a source folder') then begin
    Edit1.Text := Foldr;
    Edit2.Text := '';
    Button3.Enabled:= false;
    ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
    Button2.Enabled:= true;

  FilesList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    FindFiles(FilesList, Edit1.Text, '*.*');
    for i:= 0 to FilesList.Count-1 do
        FilesList[i] := Copy(FilesList[i], Length(Edit1.Text)+2, Length(FilesList[i]));
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(FilesList);

    Label1.Caption := 'Files found: ' + IntToStr(FilesList.Count);
  finally
    FilesList.Free;
  end;

  end else begin
    Button2.Enabled:= false;
    Button3.Enabled:= false;
    Edit1.Text := '';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Foldr: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if BrowseForFolder(Foldr, 'Select a destination folder') then begin
    Edit2.Text := Foldr;
    Button3.Enabled:= true;
    for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add(Utf8ToAnsi(Memo1.Lines[i]));
    end;
  end else begin
    Edit2.Text := '';
    Button3.Enabled:= false;
  end;
end;

procedure Split (const Delimiter: Char; Input: string; const Strings: TStrings) ;
begin
   Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
   Strings.Clear;
   Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
   Strings.DelimitedText := Input;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,j, error : Integer;
  DestDir: String;
begin
    Button1.Enabled:= false;
    Button2.Enabled:= false;
    Button3.Enabled:= false;
    StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Parsing directory names...';
    for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
    begin
      j := LastDelimiter('\', Memo2.Lines[i]);
      DestDir := '\\?\' + Edit2.Text + '\' + Copy(Memo2.Lines[i], 0, j-1);
      if not DirectoryExists(DestDir) then begin
        {$IOChecks off}
        ForceDirectories(DestDir);
        // Did the directory get created OK?
        error := IOResult;
        if error <> 0
        then ShowMessageFmt('Directory creation failed with error %d',[error]);
        {$IOChecks on}
      end;
    end;
    StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Copying...';
    for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if ProgressBar1.Position <> Round((100/Memo1.Lines.Count) * i) then begin
        ProgressBar1.Position := Round((100/Memo1.Lines.Count) * i);
        Button3.Caption := IntToStr(Round((100/Memo1.Lines.Count) * i)) + '%';
      end;
      CopyFile(PChar('\\?\' + Edit1.Text + '\' + Memo1.Lines[i]), PChar('\\?\' + Edit2.Text + '\' + Memo2.Lines[i]), False);
    end;
    Button1.Enabled:= True;
    ProgressBar1.Position := 100;
    Button2.Enabled:= True;
    Button3.Enabled:= True;
    Button3.Caption := 'Convert';
    StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Ready!';
    ShowMessageFmt('Converted %d files', [i]);
end;
end.
```

Comment: -1: Perhaps you should post the source instead of directly linking to an executable. Using `WideCharToMultiByte` WIN32 API function does not need a full executable/projet/whatever. This is a forum for developers to share sources/examples, not executable link repository.

Comment: Unchecked my "-1" (the downmod I put on this answer, that is) after the link to an executable was replaced by 200 lines of Delphi sources. The question still belongs elsewhere, through...

Comment: Note that ANSI is not CP866... Anyway, I have doubts about using this source to successfully convert Russian UTF-8 filenames into correct DOS-visible filenames on my french-based Windows XP (I don't have Delphi, so I won't even try...).

Comment: In MS-land, "ANSI" is often used to mean "the OEM code page", which just means "whatever the glyphs in the video ROM happen to be". Setting the correct UTF-16 names is the "right" thing to do; whether they'll appear correctly in "DOS" is another issue.

Comment: It's not just DOS, there are other standards and appliances to consider. Notably FTP where it is still used. Traditionally it hates Unicode.